# Display User teams in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have 3 models - Project, Team and a CustomUser model. I'm trying to display a list of teams which a user is part of on the user's detail page, and display a list of users who are part of the project team on the project's detail page but I'm at a stand-still.

```
# project/users/models.py

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Relationship Fields
    team = models.ManyToManyField(
        'users.Team',
        related_name="teams",
    )

class Team(models.Model):
    # Relationship Fields
    project = models.OneToOneField(
        'projects.Project',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="projects", 
    )
```

```
# project/projects/models.py

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

## project/projects/templates/projects/project_detail.html

```
{% for user in project.team.user.all %}
    {{ user.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried variations of the above such as

```
{% for user in users.teams.projects.all %}
    {{ user.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

but I can't seem to make anything show. I think I'm doing something simple wrong - I've read through the docs for displaying ManyToManyFields but I'm at a loss! Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not sure but i think related_name are missed used in this situation:

```
class Team(models.Model):
# Relationship Fields
project = models.OneToOneField(
    'projects.Project',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="projects", 
)
```

this means that in one object of the class Project will have an attribute with the name projects that will be a reference to the teams. I believe you want:

```
class Team(models.Model):
# Relationship Fields
project = models.OneToOneField(
    'projects.Project',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="team", 
)
```

So you will be able to call project.team.

Changing your code:

```
# project/users/models.py

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Relationship Fields
    team = models.ManyToManyField(
        'users.Team',
        related_name="customers",
    )

class Team(models.Model):
    # Relationship Fields
    project = models.OneToOneField(
        'projects.Project',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="team", 
    )

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So in the template now you could:

```
{% for user in project.team.customers.all %}
    {{ user.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: that was it! just needed to change the template to ```project.teams.users.all``` ! thank you!